# Javascript How do I check that input value is neither empty or not a number?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the value the user enter in one of my input. I want to check both that the value entered is neither an empty string or not a number. How do I do this, please?

```
const tempInput = parseInt(document.querySelector("#temp").value); 
// this is my input

if (tempInput === '' || tempInput !== Nan){
  code block
}
```

this is not working unfortunately!
Thanks!!

Comment: You should use `isNaN()` method to check if the input is not a number.
sample usage `isNaN("test")`

Comment: In HTML 5, the input.pattern field is the best way to do this

Comment: And no need to check if `tempInput === ''`, that can't happen after you used `parseInt` on it. Just `if (isNaN(tempInput)) { /* the input is invalid */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var theInput = document.getElementById("temp");
var regex = /(?:[A-Za-z].*?\d|\d.*?[A-Za-z])/;

theInput.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    if(theInput.value.length == 0){
       console.log("Is empty");
    } else if(!!theInput.value.match(regex)){
        console.log("Both number and characters");
    } else if(theInput.value.length > 0 && !isNaN(theInput.value)){
        console.log("Number");
    } else {
      console.log("NOT a Number");
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="temp" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = document.getElementById("temp").value;
if(value.length > 0 && !isNaN(value))
{
    //code
}
```